# Using Blueprism, How to right click on a web application and select an option using Key or Click events?

Tags: popup, browser-automation, blueprism, rpa

Using BluePrism, how to right click on a web application and select an option *using Key or Click* events in `Region Mode` or `Accessibility Mode`?

It doesn't spy any of the menu items with an error saying :

***Unable to spy the element***

Comment: Based on your tags and the error you say you've encountered, it sounds like you're dealing with a popup whose window model is not part of the original program's. Can you provide a screenshot of the problematic window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it with the following:

Because the window that shows up is a System window, it means it's no longer part of the IE Application Modeller, as it's using a different thread and a different ID.

So you'll need to create a different object specifically for this operation. I created one with

Object Name: IE - Popup Message

Window Title: Message from webpage

Windows Process iexplore

When attaching to it use index of 0, and then you can easily use UI Automation or Acessibility to identify the button you want to press.

But yes, you'll need to use a different object, I'd suggest making this one and every time there's a system popup for IE to identify the different buttons and use this object as a common interface between them.

Answer (score 1):

This needs clear details about right-click behaviour; where is it showing a specific menu item or general right-click option.

In case application-specific option ->

then you can select global mouse click with text as 'right' to select the menu item and then finally using the Arrow keys (Up, Down to move the desired location )